# How does a processor handle different data types?

Tags: assembly, types, theory, machine-code

What does a machine do to differentiate between interpretation protocols between data types, for example: between 1-byte, 2-byte, 4-byte integers , floats, doubles, chars, and Unicode formats?

I hypothesize that there is some sort of heading notation to distinguish between configurations of sets of operations valid for the data type that makes up a portion of the final executable, but I would like a precise answer if anyone is willing to explain.

Comment: There are different "versions" of the same instructions that take different type-widths, or different instructions entirely. Also, processors don't know about Unicode (or arguably even the notion of 'characters'), nor is Unicode a specific "type".

Comment: For example see the resources in http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html - and follow the one to ADD (http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ADD.html); note that here, for x86, there are numerous different forms of "ADD" that work on different data sizes (but "ADD" is only for integers). These different forms all have slightly different encodings - mainly a different "OP CODE", which is the actual processor instruction. For x86, there are different "ADD*" instructions entirely for floating-point types.

Comment: This differs from one processor to another.

Comment: Does the processor have specific circuitry built to handle the addition operation for different integer sizes? Or is the byte size setting implied by the version of the instruction and is implemented to affect exactly the amount of bits to implement the addition algorithm? I'm thinking that at some point a setting option for 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes must be implemented, and am assuming that the designation is hard-wired into how each assembler instruction is implemented at the circuitry level so that memory need not be used to specify integer types. Thanks for pointing me to the resource!

Comment: It is certainly possible to make a processor that has different adders for different widths, but quite wasteful.  You do get better overall performance if trying for a single cycle addition, but if you advertise one clock addition for various widths then you just wasted logic making different ones, the slowest one, the widest, has to finish in the same amount of time, so just use it for everything with extra taps on the carry outs and signed overflow locations that are muxed to the one output carried to the flags.

Comment: If you were to offer say 8 bit add in one clock cycle and tune the processor for that then 16 and 32 and 64 bit widths would take some to many clock cycles to complete in that system.  And of course add is not the long pole in your tent so it is not driving the clock rate limits, its a freebie relative to others so no reason to waste the logic.

Comment: My hypothesis is considering whether there is a logic gate construct that sets the amount of logic gates to use in the addition algorithm, or if there are dedicated logic circuits for handling addition for each integer size. Since there are only a fixed number of integer sizes, I'm assuming that the logic gate construct I am hypothesizing does not exist and that the latter option is true. Is this so?

Comment: Why hypothesize there are a plethora of open source processor designs out there just go look at them.  And most definitely no reason whatsoever to assume that one design drives the world.  Processors are like programs, give 100 engineers an instruction set and you get somewhere between 1 and 100 differen designs leaning toward the latter.  Give 100 programmers the same task, convert a srec file to an ihex file, and you get closer to 100 different solutions, might be similar in design, but different in implementation.

Comment: addition is done one column at a time for as many bits wide as you have, if you want to build an x86 adder and you have to build a 64 bit one that settles in one clock cycle, then you just tap the carry in and carry out at bits 7, 15, 31 and of course 63, using those to generate unsigned and signed overflow. use a mux based on the width to pick which one of the four sets, rather than build four different adders and mux the operands to them and results from rather than dealing with 8 bits and one mux. that would be more sane IMO, but it us up to the individual designer as to exactly what to do.

Comment: now with hdls and compilers and different foundries processes and cell libraries, what does that hdl actually compile to, does the "programmer" care at that level or leave it up to the compiler and optimizer (same answer as a high level language programmer for software, generally they leave it up to the compiler).  Now the lilbrary may have modules for addition and the compiler might wire those up, you might have several adders in there due to the nature of how the processor was designed and compiled.

Comment: more things to ponder, how do processors without flags and only offer conditionals on equal or not equal deal with greater than or less than at the width of the registers?  they dont the programmer or compiler does...

Comment: A processor knows nothing more than: zero, one, and, or, not.  thats it that is the extent of its intelligence.

Answer (score 3):

Processors/logic in general doesnt know one bit from another, that is primarily in the eyes of the user or programmer.  When computing an address for example

*ptr++;

the pointer is just bits at some address which is just bits so you put some bits in a register then you do a read from those bits for that one clock cycle as those bits move toward the main bus(es) those bits are an address, some bits come back they are just bits, they go in a register.  Those bits are sent to the alu with constant that pointer could be to a structure so ++ could be some number other than one, in either case, it is sent along as well, or in some architectures you have to load it into a register first.  the alu does some math on those bits, for those few clock cycles those bits are operands.  addition and subtraction dont know about unsigned vs signed so it is just bits.  those fall out say into a register, and now we write those bits to the address we used before which is only an address for the one/few clock cycles it is sampled from a register and sent on its way.

float is just bits sent to the fpu.

byte, halfword, word, doubleword, etc transfers are driven by the instruction or other logic (a fetch is not done with instructions normally) on a read with modern 32 or 64 or so width busses the read is of the whole width and as it gets to the processor core the byte lanes of interest are stripped off, depends on the architecture and bus of course, writes for targets that accept bytes halfwords words will have some scheme either a bytemask indicating which lanes are valid (vs which lanes which are dont cares) or there will be a size in units of bytes and both sides agree to align those bytes on the bus in a certain way (bit lanes 0 to n-1 would make most sense but whatever they design).

Now computer languages which are generally not computer friendly have lots of opinions about bits, this variable is this type and that variable is that type and in some languages if I want to "convert" 8 bits from one type to another an ascii character to a data byte I have to some kind of conversion which is of course dead code as there is no such thing as ascii nor a data byte in the processor.  Now sometimes there are conversions that do matter, perhaps even the data one if the byte is not stored as a byte but is in a register, then if unsigned a sign extension has to happen.

Most of this is trivial to see if you disassemble your code for whatever language you are using.  You will eventually find for example that on a 32 or 64 bit computer it is inefficient to try to save space and use 8 bit variables rather than 32 or 64 as the compiler has to add masking and sign extension for the folks that tend to use signed integers.

Note the processor doesnt know instructions from data either, whatever is fed in is what it consumes as instructions.  It is up to the programmer and compiler to not ask it to consume bits as instructions that are not instructions.  There are no magic bits in the patterns to indicate data from instruciton.  There is the academic "harvard architecture" but those really dont work well in the real world, modern processors are generally modified harvard as they use one main bus but tag transactions as instruction fetches or data cycles (so if you have an i cache vs d cache you can sort them).

bits is bits, they have no meaning to the computer, only to the humans.

EDIT

```
char *ptr;
float f;
void more_fun ( float );
void fun ( void )
{
    ptr=(char *)0x3000;
    *ptr++=5;
    *ptr++=4;
    *ptr++=6;
    f=1.0F;
    more_fun(f);
}
```

with one compiler for one processor gives

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e3a02a03    mov r2, #12288  ; 0x3000
   4:   e3a00005    mov r0, #5
   8:   e3a01004    mov r1, #4
   c:   e59f304c    ldr r3, [pc, #76]   ; 60 <fun+0x60>
  10:   e59fc04c    ldr r12, [pc, #76]  ; 64 <fun+0x64>
  14:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
  18:   e583c000    str r12, [r3]
  1c:   e5c20000    strb    r0, [r2]
  20:   e5932000    ldr r2, [r3]
  24:   e2820001    add r0, r2, #1
  28:   e5830000    str r0, [r3]
  2c:   e3a0e006    mov lr, #6
  30:   e5c21000    strb    r1, [r2]
  34:   e3a025fe    mov r2, #1065353216 ; 0x3f800000
  38:   e5931000    ldr r1, [r3]
  3c:   e59fc024    ldr r12, [pc, #36]  ; 68 <fun+0x68>
  40:   e2810001    add r0, r1, #1
  44:   e5830000    str r0, [r3]
  48:   e5c1e000    strb    lr, [r1]
  4c:   e1a00002    mov r0, r2
  50:   e58c2000    str r2, [r12]
  54:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <more_fun>
  58:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  5c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  60:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
  64:   00003001    andeq   r3, r0, r1
  68:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

this is unlinked.

it puts the address of ptr in a register (this is also optimized), it preps some of the constants.  It gets the address to ptr (global variable so at compile time it doesnt know where it is, so it has to leave a place it can reach for the linker to fill in, in other instruction sets same problem but the "location" is a immediate to the instruction and the instruction is incomplete until link time, but the space is left either way).  for each ptr++ we have to save back to the global as it is global so r3 holds the address to ptr for the duration.

```
ldr r12, [pc, #76]  ; 64 <fun+0x64>
```

ahh a missed optimization opportunity add r12,r2,#1 would have been much cheaper.

so ptr+1 is saved to ptr in memory (these are all bits to the processor notice how it doesnt know this is a pointer nor a signed pointer some of these bits are an address but only when the register is used as an address is it an address.

```
add r0, r2, #1
```

here the bits we think of as an address are just bits being added.

```
str r0, [r3]
```

and just bits being stored.

```
mov r2, #1065353216 ; 0x3f800000
```

Floating point 1.0 single precision, just bits

as far as the notion that cisc vs risc treat things differently cisc uses smaller registers and cisc uses 32 or 64 bit.

```
unsigned short fun ( unsigned short x )
{
    return(x+0x1000);
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e2800a01    add r0, r0, #4096   ; 0x1000
   4:   e1a00800    lsl r0, r0, #16
   8:   e1a00820    lsr r0, r0, #16
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr


0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   8d 87 00 10 00 00       lea    0x1000(%rdi),%eax
   6:   c3                      retq
```

the arm is at least honoring the 16 bit boundary, hopefully x86 takes care of that somewhere else.

```
unsigned short fun ( void  )
{
    return(sizeof(unsigned short));
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e3a00002    mov r0, #2
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   b8 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%eax
   5:   c3                      retq
```

EDIT 2

taking some code from opencores this processor offers an 8 or 16 bit addition and this is a not unexpected solution.

```
wire [16:0] alu_add        = op_src_in_jmp + op_dst_in;

wire    V           = inst_bw ? ((~op_src_in[7]  & ~op_dst_in[7]  &  alu_out[7])  |
                                 ( op_src_in[7]  &  op_dst_in[7]  & ~alu_out[7])) :
                                ((~op_src_in[15] & ~op_dst_in[15] &  alu_out[15]) |
                                 ( op_src_in[15] &  op_dst_in[15] & ~alu_out[15]));

wire    N           = inst_bw ?  alu_out[7]       : alu_out[15];
wire    Z           = inst_bw ? (alu_out[7:0]==0) : (alu_out==0);
wire    C           = inst_bw ?  alu_out[8]       : alu_out_nxt[16];
```

used a single 16 bit adder but muxed the flags based on 8 or 16 bit operation.  now what does the verilog compiler actually produce?  it is quite possible that it daisy chains two 8 bit adders together so it can tap off the flag results. or maybe there is a 16 bit adder in the library with these flags already tapped into.

EDIT

As far as the size of the data, the width.  That is encoded indirectly or directly in the instruction.  As shown above this becomes a control signal or signals in how the data is handled.  Take an ARM and do a byte wide read, you get a 32 or 64 bit read because there is no reason not to.  then as the data hits the core the byte lane is selected, if the instruction is designed to sign extend then it will and save the data read with its zero padding or sign extension into the register defined in the instruction.  Similar on other architectures with busses wider than a byte, although it is possible to have the target isolate the byte rather than the processor core, just depends on the bus design and I bet there is at least one example of each out there.  Since memory tends to be in bus widths or multiples it doesnt cost you more to read a whole row of the ram and move it or at least a bus width.  Fractions of the widt have a (generally minimal) cost, no need to burn that cost on both ends so pick one.  Writes are the painful one, anything less than the width of the ram causes a read-modify-write by the controller.  The instruction directly or indirectly indicates the width which is encoded on the bus in some way, the memory controller right near the ram has to deal with the fraction.  This is one of the benefits you get from a cache, even though most dram dimms are made from either 8 bit wide or 16 bit wide parts they are accessed in 64 bit widths, the cache line is such that it is one or more widths of the dram so you dont have to do read-modify-writes against such a slow memory, the read-modify-writes happen against the sram in the cache which is relatively much faster.

Performance comes from alignment, as you can reduce the logic and be more efficient do an stm of four registers on an arm if 32 bit aligned but not 64 bit against a 64 bit wide bus you have to have three transfers one for the first word, one for the next two and one for the third and the first and last require a bytemask for the bus as they dont fill it but if the same four register stm is at a 64 bit aligned address it is a single transfer.  Each transfer requiring a few to many clocks of overhead.  Likewise on the ram end if you are aligned and a full width or multiple of the memory width then it just writes, if any part of the transaction is a fraction then it has to read-modify-write.  If your cache ram happened to be 64 bits wide in the above stm combinations one would not only be slower for the bus overhead but also at the ram where you have three writes two of them read-modify writes rather than two clean writes in as few as two clock cycles.  Likely one of the reasons why the arm eabi changed to request the stack be aligned on 64 bit boundaries and the countless questions at SO as to why is this extra register being pushed when it isnt used.

As shown above in order to mask/pad the upper bits the compiler chose to shift twice knowing the second zero pads, had this been a signed int the compiler may very well have chosen a signed shift to sign extend the result to 32 bits.

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e2800a01    add r0, r0, #4096   ; 0x1000
   4:   e1a00800    lsl r0, r0, #16
   8:   e1a00820    lsr r0, r0, #16
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Ideally wanting to convert on the way into or out of the registers the size the compiler/human wanted into the native size of the register due to the architecture.  For x86 you can pull flags at the various points so you dont need to sign extend or zero pad, later operations can do the math ignoring the upper bits and pulling the flags from the middle as needed.

Now mips could have anded off the upper bits to zero them in one instruction based on how their immediates work.  Intel burns a ton of instruction space with immediates, and can do any size. (compensated by other instructions that are very small).  had it been an 8 bit data type

```
unsigned char fun ( unsigned char x )
{
    return(x+0x10);
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e2800010    add r0, r0, #16
   4:   e20000ff    and r0, r0, #255    ; 0xff
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

the compiler knew better than to do the two shifts to zero pad.

but as one would expect

```
signed char fun ( signed char x )
{
    return(x+0x10);
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e2800010    add r0, r0, #16
   4:   e1a00c00    lsl r0, r0, #24
   8:   e1a00c40    asr r0, r0, #24
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

---

I can take a really big container of assorted lego blocks, and with those blocks I could build a house, I could build a bridge, etc.  The blocks dont know a house from a bridge only the human does.  The processor doesnt know a bool from an int from an unsigned int, some know some different widths in that they can mask, pad, or sign extend but the human and the compiler know all and assemble the correct mixture of lego blocks in the correct order to implement their vision.

Comment: A processor very much *does* care about 'types'; what is the result of `200 + 200`? Languages have to map *their* definition of types on how a processor operates, but this does not make the processor entirely type-agnostic.. just concerned with a different type domain.

Comment: (And, for compatibility and ease of this mapping and to avoid emulation, a number of common language types map to well-supported processor types.)

Comment: the processor doesnt care the compiler cares.  addition is a series of three bit two output adders (carry in, operand a, operand b  -> result to carry out) all wired together however wide the alu is 8, 16, 32 whatever.  the processor is not capable of knowing these types.  these types are NOT these types as used in the compiler as I have trivially demonstrated.

Comment: They *are types* - the widths, and rules around operations (and "just the bits" they work on) - to the processor, as I previously indicated.

Comment: These types are specific to the COMPILER and PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE, not the processor.  And as such the humans care about programming in the programming language per its rules which involve these types.  So the question really isnt about what does the processor know, it is what does the compiler generate, that is an interesting question, the processor is about as dumb as it gets.

Comment: Again, processors have "types" as well as compilers and programing languages.

Comment: as I trivially demonstrated the compiler didnt care about the width either

Comment: one case where you will see a type is when you have an N*N = 2N (N=bits) multiplication, and you specify unsigned or signed multiplication, if you care about the upper N bits of the result, the lower N bits do not change between signed and unsigned.   Floating point units sure when the operation happens treats the bits differently than a fixed point unit.

Comment: division has the same problem as multiplication with signed vs signed, it all has to do with padding.  an N*N=N bit multiply doesnt though as signed and unsiged give the same result (just like addition and subtraction because multiply is just shifting and adding)

Comment: Possibly the word "type" is being used differently by different commenters, there are at least 5 definitions of "type" so that would be nothing new. Assigning the type `BitVector k` to everything gives everything a type, in that sense there might be types, but only trivially. Meanwhile, "A programming language is *untyped* if it allows to apply any operation on any data, and all datatypes are considered as sequences of bits of various lengths" which certainly applies here.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't.

On x86, the operand size is encoded as part of the instruction.  Any time two differently sized operands are used, the smaller one needs to be extended to the size of the larger one first.  Depending on the specific operation, this is either done using zero-extension (upper bits filled with zero) or sign-extension (upper bit of smaller value copied to upper bits of new value).  For example, a program might use the `movsx` instruction to sign-extend a value before using it for some other operation.

On RISC architectures, usually operations apply to entire words (eg, 32 or 64 bits) at a time and it's up to the software to know how to interpret the resulting bits.

Floating point values are handled by different circuitry than integer values and as such are stored in a separate set of registers.

Comment: *Any time two differently sized operands are used, the smaller one is extended to the size of the larger one.*  Are you talking about C?  x86 doesn't generally let you mix operand sizes.  `add rax, edx` is not encodeable.  There are instructions to zero or sign extend, and there are some instructions that pack to narrower formats.  e.g. `cvtsd2si eax, xmm0` converts a 64-bit `double` to a 32-bit integer.  Or maybe you're talking about immediate operands, where `add r64, imm8` sign-extends the immediate to 64 bits.

Comment: Anyway yes, RISC usually only has full-register sized ops.  (Or on 64-bit RISC machines, sometime 32-bit versions of some common instructions are also provided that also truncate the result to 32-bit, saving instructions when that's what the compiler needs.  Or some 64-bit RISC ISAs will have a 32-bit version of everything.  I think AArch64 is like that, where you can use the 32-bit subset of a register.)

Comment: @PeterCordes You're absolutely right, I couldn't remember if that was legal so I kept my wording a bit vague.  I've clarified my answer.